# Can I assert that a C# method has a certain attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes, nunit

```
[DummyAttribute]
public void DummyMethod() {
  return;
}
```

I want to write a Nunit test that will assert that *DummyMethod* is decorated with *DummyAttribute*, can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with reflection. One possible solution:

```
var dummyAttribute = typeof(YourClassName)
    .GetMethod(nameof(YourClassName.DummyMethod))!
    .GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false)
    .OfType<DummyAttribute>()
    .SingleOrDefault();

Assert.That(dummyAttribute, Is.Not.Null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was going on the way to find all the methods with said custom attribute in loaded assembly, then look for my  method, but this is way more efficient

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of tests are often useful to define the functional specification of the codebase.

@kardo's code is absolutely fine and seems it solved your problem as well.

However, if anyone looks for more descriptive unit tests later to specify the functional specs, then I would suggest giving a try on [fluent assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/typesandmethods/).

```
typeof(YourClassName).GetMethod(nameof(YourClassName.DummyMethod)).Should().BeDecoratedWith<DummyAttribute>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reflect or use "fluent assertions" package.

Alternatively, since you're using NUnit already...

```
Assert.That(typeof(YourClassName).GetMethod(nameof(SomeMethod)),
    Has.Attribute(typeof(DummyAttribute)));
```

Comment: I did not know about that package, thanks for the info !